# User Alerts on Site Pages will show weird page title something as follow "gzrhq4z3.aspx"

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, modern-experience, sitepages

I have set a user alert inside my "Site Pages" library, as follow:-

[image]

but when users add new modern site page, sometimes i will get the page title inside the users' alerts email, containing random characters as follow:-

[image]

while the link will take me to the correct modern site page, but not sure why i got this weird title inside the user alerts email? 
Also on other alerts' emails the page title will be correct + the email will contain  all the fields inside the content, as follow (so the email will have different format):-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please?

Comment: Hi John, this is OOTB behavior of Site pages. when ever user create Modern Site page by default it create a page with random number and characters as you mentioned above. if user just leave this page as it is without entering the page name page will still stay in Site pages Library with random name. In your case may be alert you setup immediately so when the user creates the page and editing for some time you receive the notification.but when you browse you see the page is correct. I would suggest you can Schedule your alerts instead of Immediately.

Comment: Before you provide such advice as setting up "Scheduled alerts to be send a daily summary" just test it. Its makes things even worst. Its not a solution for this issue. Regards
Slavo